# How can I get analytical form of GTO primitives for a atom?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, basis-set

As I know, for Hydrogen atom a $1s$ Slater Type Orbital (STO) equation is (I can get it from [here](https://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Slater_orbital.html)):

\begin{equation}\label{STO}
    \mathrm{STO} = \sqrt{\frac{\zeta^3}{\pi}} e^{-\zeta r}.
\end{equation}

With remark from Szabo A., Ostlund N.S. Modern Quantum Chemistry: Intro to Advanced Electronic Structure Theory, Dover, 1996:

> For example, the standard exponent  for the $1s$ basis function of hydrogen is , $\zeta = 1.24$. This is larger than the $\zeta = 1.00$ exponent of the hydrogen atom, since the hydrogen $1s$ orbital in average molecules is known to be "smaller" or "denser" than in the atom.

Gaussian Type Orbital (GTO) equation for $1s$-orbital (where did this coefficient $\left(\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}$ come from?):

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{GTO} = \left(\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}\right)^{3/4} e^{-\alpha r^2}
\end{equation}

So, I have good analitical form of Hydrogen STO and GTO, and using formula
\begin{equation}\label{}
    \sqrt{\frac{\zeta^3}{\pi}}e^{-\zeta r} \approx C_1 \left(\frac{2\alpha_1}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_1 r^2} +  C_2 \left(\frac{2\alpha_2}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_2 r^2} +  C_3 \left(\frac{2\alpha_3}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_2 r^2}.
\end{equation}
and copyng $\alpha_i$'s and $C_i$ from [basissetexchange.org](https://www.basissetexchange.org)

```
#-----------------------------------------------------
# Basis Set Exchange
# Version v0.8.13
# https://www.basissetexchange.org
#-----------------------------------------------------
#   Basis set: STO-3G
# Description: STO-3G Minimal Basis (3 functions/AO)
#        Role: orbital
#     Version: 1  (Data from Gaussian09)
#-----------------------------------------------------


BASIS "ao basis" PRINT
#BASIS SET: (3s) -> [1s]
H    S
      0.3425250914E+01       0.1543289673E+00
      0.6239137298E+00       0.5353281423E+00
      0.1688554040E+00       0.4446345422E+00
END
```

I can plot Hydrogen orbital

[image]

Now I want to do the same for a Lithium atom using data

```
BASIS "ao basis" PRINT
#BASIS SET: (6s,3p) -> [2s,1p]
Li    S
      0.1611957475E+02       0.1543289673E+00
      0.2936200663E+01       0.5353281423E+00
      0.7946504870E+00       0.4446345422E+00
Li    SP
      0.6362897469E+00      -0.9996722919E-01       0.1559162750E+00
      0.1478600533E+00       0.3995128261E+00       0.6076837186E+00
      0.4808867840E-01       0.7001154689E+00       0.3919573931E+00
END
```

But, I do not understand where I can get a analitical formula for GTO's primitives. All of references,  I saw:
\begin{equation}\label{GTO}
\mathrm{GTO}(x,y,z;\alpha,\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3) = N  x^{\ell_1} y^{\ell_2} z^{\ell_3} e^{-\alpha r^2}
\end{equation}
with  unknown normalizing factor $N$. Sometimes I saw for $1p$-orbital
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{GTO}(p_x) = \left(\frac{128\alpha^5}{\pi^3}\right)^{1/4} x \exp(-\alpha r^2)
\end{equation}
but I don't understand where the factor $\left(\frac{128\alpha^5}{\pi^3}\right) $ comes from.
So, my general question: where can I see the analytical view of the GTO primitive (like for [STO's](https://www.theochem.ru.nl/%7Epwormer/Knowino/knowino.org/wiki/Slater_orbital.html)), and how can you find $\zeta$ for atom obital? (how to read such data?)

Comment: I believe this website (http://www.ccl.net/cca/documents/basis-sets/basis.html ) might be helpful, even if it does not answer all the questions. For the 1s STO-3G orbital, the $\mathrm{(\frac{2\alpha}{\pi})^{3/4}}$ is in fact, the normalization constant. So I believe that for the p orbitals (or other orbitals) you only need the C and $\alpha$, then you can normalize that. The 'factor' that you see is in fact the algebraic form of the normalization constant.

Answer (score 4):

Main differenece betweet STO's and GTO's is a $r$-expotetnt. Normalizing factor of GTO one can get from common procedure:
\begin{equation}
N^2 \int_0^\infty \left(r^{n-1}e^{-\zeta r^2}\right)^2 r^2 dr =1 
\end{equation}
Of course, computation is not so simple for $n > 1$, but we can use online [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Assume%5Bn%3D2+%26%26+a%3E0%2C%5B1%2Fsqrt%5BIntegrate+%28r%5E%28n-1%29*exp%28-a*r%5E2%29%29%5E2*r%5E2%2C%7Br%2C0%2Cinfinity%7D%5D%5D%5D) (clickable calculation) and we get the formulas from the question post.

For a Lithium atom we have contraction (6s,3p) -> [2s,1p], which means
the first **3s** of 6s GTO's cotract to one **s** "1s"-STO
$$\mathrm{STO}(1s) = \sqrt{\frac{\zeta^3}{\pi}} e^{-\zeta_1 r},$$
second **3s** of 6s GTO's contract to another **s** "2s"-STO
$$\mathrm{STO}(2s) = \sqrt{\frac{\zeta^5}{3\pi}} r e^{-\zeta_2 r},$$
**3p** GTO's contract to one **p** - "2p"-STO
$$\mathrm{STO}(2p) = \sqrt{\frac{\zeta_2^5}{\pi}} x e^{-\zeta_2 r}$$
(notation in orbitals in quotation marks "1s", "2s" means the same as for the hydrogen atom). So, as we can see, every atomic STO contract by only 3 GTO's (which justifies their name).

---

For a Litium atom we have for "1s" atomic orbital
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\zeta_1^3}{\pi}} e^{-\zeta_1 r} \approx 
C_1 \left(\frac{2\alpha_1}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_1 r^2} + 
C_2 \left(\frac{2\alpha_2}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_2 r^2} +
C_3 \left(\frac{2\alpha_3}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_3 r^2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 = 0.1611957475E+02; C_1 = 0.1543289673E+00;\\
\alpha_2 = 0.2936200663E+01; C_2 = 0.5353281423E+00;\\
\alpha_3 = 0.7946504870E+00; C_3 = 0.4446345422E+00;
\end{align}
[image]

For "2s" atomic orbital
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\zeta_2^5}{3\pi}} r e^{-\zeta_2 r} \approx 
C_4 \left(\frac{2\alpha_1}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_4 r^2} + 
C_5 \left(\frac{2\alpha_2}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_5 r^2} +
C_6 \left(\frac{2\alpha_3}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}e^{-\alpha_6 r^2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\alpha_4 = 0.6362897469E+00; C_4 = -0.9996722919E-01;\\ 
\alpha_5 = 0.1478600533E+00; C_5 = 0.3995128261E+00; \\ 
\alpha_6 = 0.4808867840E-01; C_6 = 0.7001154689E+00;  
\end{align}
[image]
For "2p_x" atomic orbital
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\zeta_2^5}{\pi}} x e^{-\zeta_2 r} \approx 
D_1 \left(\frac{128\alpha_4^5}{\pi^3}\right)^{1/4} xe^{-\alpha_4 r^2} + 
D_2 \left(\frac{128\alpha_5^5}{\pi^3}\right)^{1/4} xe^{-\alpha_5 r^2} +
D_3 \left(\frac{128\alpha_6^5}{\pi^3}\right)^{1/4} xe^{-\alpha_6 r^2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\alpha_4 = 0.6362897469E+00; D_1 = 0.1559162750E+00;;\\ 
\alpha_5 = 0.1478600533E+00; D_2 = 0.6076837186E+00; \\ 
\alpha_6 = 0.4808867840E-01; D_3 = 0 0.3919573931E+00;  
\end{align}
[image]
(For $p_y$ and $p_z$ --- do the same)

Also, for STO's best fit $\zeta_1 = 2.69$ and $\zeta_2 = 0.81$ are consistent with those given in the article Hehre, W. J., Ditchfield, R., Stewart, R. F., & Pople, J. A. (1970). Self‐Consistent Molecular Orbital Methods. IV. Use of Gaussian Expansions of Slater‐Type Orbitals. Extension to Second‐Row Molecules. The Journal of Chemical Physics, 52(5), 2769–2773. doi:10.1063/1.1673374